# Cleaner Python suggestions

Tags: python

Curious if there's a more concise way to set these form values instead of just listing them one by one. The `venue_items` dictionary doesn't contain any extra (key, value) pairs that aren't declared here if that makes any difference.

```
    form.name.data = venue_items["name"]
    form.city.data = venue_items["city"]
    form.state.data = venue_items["state"]
    form.address.data = venue_items["address"]
    form.phone.data = venue_items["phone"]
    form.image_link.data = venue_items["image_link"]
    form.facebook_link.data = venue_items["facebook_link"]
    form.genres.data = venue_items["genres"]
    form.website.data = venue_items["website"]
    form.seeking_talent.data = venue_items["seeking_talent"]
    form.seeking_description.data = venue_items["seeking_description"]
```

Comment: It really depends on what `form` is. If it's just a normal object with a `__dict__`, you can simplify, or not even do the assignment at all. If it's a set of descriptors, you're SOL.

Comment: @MadPhysicist nah, you can use `getattr`, that will invoke the decriptor protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, there is a way to do this dynamically, something like:

```
for key, value in venue_items.items():
    getattr(form, key).data = value
```

Or if your dict contains extra key-value pairs that wouldn't be used, something like:

```
keys = ["name", "city", "state", "address", "phone", "image_link", "facebook_link",
        "genres", "website", "seeking_talent",  "seeking_description"]

for key in keys:
    getattr(form, key).data = venue_items[key]
```